# R.dll causing Error

Tags: java, jri

I am trying to execute R code using rJava but on setting R.dll path in the environment variables causing the program to crash. The program crashes on executing any R function. I also tried to run jri example but no help.

[image]

Any solution or hint would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(If your using net beans) You should show the JVM the path (JRI.dll) in the following way:

[image]

To be more specific you need to point the following :

```
-Djava.library.path='C:/Users/yschellekens.INTRANET/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/rJava/jri/x64/'
```

to where the **JRI.dll is located**, although this might not be your problem, since when i'm removing the path in Netbeans, i get the following error (which is different from yours):

```
run:
Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jri in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
    at stackoverflow.StackOverflow.main(StackOverflow.java:21)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

hope that helps.